# Cleaning out laptop hinges and buttons after a soda spill

Tags: laptop, cleaning

I had a soda spill on my laptop. I only had technical issues with the keyboard but I fixed that by purchasing a new keyboard part. However, I still have issues with stickyness on the hinges between the monitor and the laptop, and a couple of buttons.

Any suggestions on how to clean this up?

**Note:** I'm assuming this will require some sort of distilled water or something. Just mentioning that because I'm willing to let it dry out for as long as it takes. Just want to get rid of the stickiness.

Comment: Actually it's bad idea to use for example distilled water, because there is all kind of bad stuff (as in soda, salt etc.), that will dissolve, and short circuit electronics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with rubbing alcohol

Comment: If you can find 91% or 99% isopropyl it's better than 70%. That 30% water can take a while to dry.

Answer (score 0):

I would use anti-static electronics cleaner such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000V1A7Q)